# Oracle - How to raise application error from a function

Tags: oracle, function

Why does this not raise an application error? If I execute the same code in an anonymous block it works i.e. raises an application error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION uf_todate(dt IN date)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN
  IF dt < to_date('01.01.1900','dd.mm.yyyy') THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'Date is less than 1/1/1900.');
  END IF;

  RETURN nvl(upper(to_char(dt ,'dd-mon-yyyy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English')), '31-DEC-9999');
END;
```

This is Oracle 12c.

Comment: How do you _call_ the function?

Comment: It's working for me. Are you sure you correctly assigned a date value to the function parameter?

Comment: E.g. `select uf_todate(to_date('01.01.1800','dd.mm.yyyy')) from dual`. Does it have an effect if I call it from SQL Developer? It returns 01-JAN-1800.

Comment: It should not have any effect if you call it from SQL developer or SQLPLUS or PLSQL dewveloper.

Comment: @pablomatico How do you call the function and in what tool, SQLPlus, SQL Developer?

Comment: @Rubio I tried with TOAD and SQLPlus

Answer (score 0):

Looks like clicking the Commit button in SQL Developer didn't commit the changes to the function. Executing `commit;` explicitly worked.

Comment: No, `create or replace` is DDL and does not require a separate commit.

Comment: Whatever the case, entering a separate commit replaced the function and it started working.

Comment: Reproducible test case or it didn't happen.

Comment: Not reproducible.

Comment: Yup. So, do you still think this answer is correct?